Web3Button from Thirdweb-dev/React v4 SDK never loads, when set the active chain to base
I am working on a simple project,  I'm using React v4 SDK , and everything runs fine, I'm able to connect the wallet and read data from the user's wallet.
But when I set up the web3 button to sign a transaction, basically never loads. it stays rendering.
This is how my thirdweb provider is set up

root.render(
  
  <React.StrictMode>
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <ThirdwebProvider clientId={_clientId} secretKey={_secreteKey} 
           locale={spanish}
           activeChain={Base}>
             
        <App />
      </ThirdwebProvider>
    </QueryClientProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

this is the web3button component in my project
const ApproveButton = ({tokenAddress,amount}) => {
    console.log('approve component');

    const  {contract}  = useContract(tokenAddress);
    const { mutateAsync, isLoading, error } = useContractWrite(
        contract,
        'approve(address spender,uint256 amount)'
    );
    const spender = `${process.env.REACT_APP_MANGO_ROUTER00}`;

    return(
        <Web3Button
            contractAddress={tokenAddress}
            // Calls the "setName" function on your smart contract with "My Name" as the first argument
            action={() => mutateAsync({ args: [spender,amount]})}
            className="w-100" 
            style={{
                padding: "1rem",
                fontSize: "1.5rem",
                backgroundColor: "#F26E01", // Mango orange
                borderColor: "#FFA500", // Match the border color
                color: "#FFFFFF", // White text for contrast
            }}
            >Approve</Web3Button>
    );

}
export default ApproveButton;

If I remove the activeChain from the thirdwebprovider wrapper, the buttons loads fine, but can't do anything because it is not on the right chain. maybe I need to pass a rpc to the web3 button but not sure.
Basically, it stays like this and never loadsescription here
enter image description here basically us stays like this and never loads
